# java 8 lambda and JSF managedBean

Tags: java, jsf, lambda

I'm having problems trying to use java 8 `lambda` inside a `managed bean`. Depending on the `lambda` I use, the `bean` is returning `null`.

I'm using a very simple `lambda` calling a method inside `forEach`.

When I test it in a simple Java project, it works fine, but inside a `bean` it doesn't work:

```
usuarios.forEach(u -> u.tornaModerador());
```

The above code works inside a simple Java project. The code below doesn't work using `JSF 2.2` with java 8:

```
getAllauth().forEach(a -> a.activateAuth());
```

It's the same thing. Both Java objects are correct. BTW, `getAllauth()` method is not `null`.

Not all lambda aren't working inside the managed bean. The following is working properly:

```
appAuthList.removeIf(a -> !a.getApp().equalsIgnoreCase(getApp().getApp()) || a.getAuth().equals("READ"));
```

I already updated `javaassist`.

Comment: I have a problem understanding what exactly does not work. First you wrote that some bean returns null and then that expression `usuarios.forEach(u -> u.tornaModerador());` does not work. Does it mean that method u.tornaModerador() is never called? If so does it work when you replace forEach with simple `for` loop? Maybe usuarios is empty.

Comment: I also cannot get lambdas to work inside a managed bean.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue as well and discovered that it was a problem with the way annotations were being scanned by JSF. A recent update to JSF (to 2.3.0) appears to have fixed the problem. [Here](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3776) is the bug report in case you are interested.

Comment: See cloned issue https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3835, which sets the fixed version in Mojarra 2.2.11. At least that version fixed it in my case.